# Partial Differential Equation approach for ridgeplot

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, differential-equations

I have a series of probability density functions (pdfs) such that I can create a ridge plot with them evolving in time. Is it possible to know the intermediate function in between two of the functions I have sampled? i.e. I have the pdf for instants $t=1$ and $t=2$ but I know that the time evolution is continuous, is it possible to evaluate a new pdf in instant $t=1.3$ for example? I believe this could be thought of as solving a PDE in the function $f(x,t)$ where at each instant $t$ there exists a pdf $f(x,t=t')$ but I don't know how to convert this in a numerical method. Is there an algorithm for such a task?

Comment: If this is for interpolation only, I suggest to just view this as a 2D KDE estimation problem and evaluate the conditional density estimate at f(x | t = 1.3).  For extrapolation in time it's an interesting problem, maybe functional data analysis might help for fractional estimates of time ( for discrete t , it's a standard forecasting problem with conditional future density forecasts)

Comment: Where would the PDE come from?  This reads like an interpolation problem; and how one interpolates depends on assumptions about the process as well as the purpose of the interpolation.  There certainly is (therefore) no general algorithm.  Could you supply more information about the actual problem you have?

Comment: The pdfs are the result of monthly data for reservoir levels in the southern hemisphere. The pdfs move along the x-axis (x representing how much %variation there was) on what should be a periodic movement: in this region, it rains half the year while the other half is dry, so in wet months the pdfs have more are in the positive half of the cartesian plane, indicating that the reservoir level will probably go up; the mean of the pdfs should then move from a maximum value of x on the wettest month to the minimum value of x on the driest month.

Comment: Even though I have the pdfs each month, there should be a continuous of pdfs over time, so I thought that their behaviour could be modelled as something like $f(x,t) = g(x)\sin(t)$, since the pdfs follow a clearly periodic behaviour and $g(x)$ could be found via partial differential equations methods.